# How to pass a conditional operator through typescript boolean field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, boolean, conditional-operator

I've been migrating my code over to typescript and I'm trying to figure out how this conditional operator through this table component designed by Ant Design.

```
const paginationLogic = props.data.length <= 10 ? false : true
    
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Table</h1>
            <div className="w-80 m-auto site-overflow">
                <Table columns={columns} dataSource={myData}  pagination={paginationLogic} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

When I use the above code there is an error but this seems to work. I need the conditional operator because I want the pagination to kick in if there is more than 10 rows.

```
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={myData}  pagination={false} />
```

Comment: const paginationLogic: boolean = props.data.length <= 10 ? false : true;

Comment: "*When I use the above code there is an error*" - what error? Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message.

Comment: Btw, simplify that conditional operator to `const paginationLogic = !(props.data.length <= 10)` or `const paginationLogic = props.data.length > 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Type error you're getting is

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false | TablePaginationConfig | undefined'
```

Here's the updated code

```
import { TablePaginationConfig } from 'antd/es/table/Table';

const paginationConfig: TablePaginationConfig = {
//add your config here
}
const paginationLogic = props.data.length > 10 ? paginationConfig : false;
```

Please refer to the Ant typescript [documentation](https://beta-pro.ant.design/docs/type-script#table)

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false | TablePaginationConfig | undefined'